# Unable to create an azure image in ARM

Tags: azure, iaas, azure-hub

I have uploaded a back up of onprem OS disk to azure RM storage account.  I want to create an image out of that os disk to provision vms in azure.

Please let me know if that is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your base system is running Windows, and you don't want to sysprep the machine, you're trying to create what's called a Specialized image in Azure.  The best steps to follow to complete this are:

1. [Create the Specialized image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image)
2. [Create a VM from an image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to make sure that the disk is in correct format i.e VHD for azure. There are many third party tools available to convert the disk to VHD (very easy if it's hyper v machine).
Secondly do create the necessary infrastructure in azure like storage account to upload the disk and virtual network that would connect to your machine, resource group etc. Also this is currently only possible through powershell and not through portal.

Azure migarte has now made it very to migrate large number of vms if you are considering a production( much better than its was last year). 
The question says unable to migrate is disk so I assume you must have gone through Microsoft document and than must have faced problem. Can you provide me the error you got while uploading?